# Abstract conditions for a formal system to be adequate with respect to the standard semantics

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

In general, when introducing logic, we present students with a given formal system (e.g. Hilbert-style axioms, natural deduction, sequence calculi, etc.) and then, after presenting the standard semantics for first-order logic, we proceed to show that the system is adequate with respect to this semantics, i.e. it is both correct and complete. In some cases, we may even present students with several such systems, comparing their pros and cons (one system may be more cumbersome to work with, but makes it easier to prove correctness and completeness, etc.). There is something a bit unsatisfying about this since it may give the impression that it is just luck, or a historical contingency, that the systems we do have are indeed adequate to the standard semantics. Hence my question:

Can we isolate a set of necessary and sufficient conditions such that any system which satisfies them will be adequate with respect to the usual semantics?

Comment: Hmm... pick your favorite adequate system $S$. Then a necessary and sufficient condition for adequacy of $S'$ is that $S$ and $S'$ prove exactly the same theorems. This is not very satisfying, but it seems pretty unlikely to me that there is any more "natural" condition.

Comment: @AlexKruckman well, what about those abstract consistency conditions I outline in my answer? Do you think they might work?

Comment: Ah, I see. The idea is to axiomatize exactly which closure properties of consistent theories are necessary to make the model existence theorem work. I agree that this kind of criterion answers your question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have stumbled upon an answer to my question as I was perusing Smullyan's *First-Order Logic* (especially Chapter VI "A Unifying Principle"). Keisler discusses a similar idea in his *Model Theory for Infinitary Logic* (with reference to [Smullyan](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.49.6.828)) and so does Hinman in his *Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic* (pp. 63ff for the propositional case and pp. 216ff for the first-order case). I will discuss here the propositional case since it is easier.

Consider a formal system $F$, which we may suppose is sound (with respect to the standard semantics). Since it is sound, it will generate a notion of consistency. In particular, we may say that a given set of sentences $\Sigma$ is $F$-consistent iff there is at least one formula $\phi$ such that $\Sigma \not \vdash \phi$. Now, we say that this $F$-consistency notion is a *consistency property* iff for each $F$-consistent set $\Sigma$, the following holds:

(1) If $\phi \in \Sigma$, then $\neg \phi \not \in \Sigma$;

(2) If $\neg \neg \phi \in \Sigma$, then $\Sigma \cup \{\phi\}$ is also $F$-consistent;

(3) If $\phi \vee \psi \in \Sigma$, then either $\Sigma \cup \{\phi\}$ is $F$-consistent or $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\}$ is $F$-consistent;

(4) If $\phi \wedge \psi \in \Sigma$, then $\Sigma \cup \{\phi\}$ and $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\}$ are also $F$-consistent.

We then have the following theorem:

**Theorem:** If $F$-consitency is a consistency property, then any $F$-consistent set can be extended to a maximal complete set. In particular, every $F$-consistent set has a model. (See any of the references given in the first paragraph.)

If I'm not mistaken, this means that the above gives a set of necessary and sufficient conditions for a (classical) system to be adequate.